# Ubuntu 22.04 and GCC < 11

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 fresh and it turns out it is using gcc/g++11:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
```

Now, this won't work for many installation scripts and I'd like to have a way to at least keep 2-3 more gcc/g++ versions on my system. I was able to do this myself on my Ubuntu 20.04. But on this one, it keeps telling me that there is no such package on the tree.

```
sudo apt -y install gcc-7 g++-7 gcc-8 g++-8 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package gcc-8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package gcc-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-7' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-7' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'gcc-8' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-8' has no installation candidate
```

I've tried adding

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

as well, no luck. Is there a way to crack this? It would be quite silly if we could not install the previous version of gcc/g++. That would be a reason to remove 22.04 altogether.

Comment: 22.04 still has GCC 9, is that not sufficient?

Comment: Gcc9 seems to compile what gcc11 could not, so yes, that seems to suffice for now. I wonder though what happens if something that required gcc8 would show up.

Comment: In most cases you can fix projects which don’t build with newer GCCs without too much trouble, using GCC’s own porting guides ([GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/porting_to.html), [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/porting_to.html), [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html), [GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/porting_to.html), [GCC 12](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/porting_to.html)). Many problems can be fixed by specifying the language level to use (*e.g.* `-std=gnu++14`).

Comment: `Gcc9 seems to compile what gcc11 could not` that's because gcc11 may have newer default standards so you need to specify the same C/C++ standard and same other compiling options

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406962/install-gcc7-on-ubuntu-22-04